# I can't get array to work within an IF condition

Tags: arrays, if-statement, google-sheets

`=if(ArrayFormula(LOOKUP(2,1/($K$1:$K10="Distributed"),($B$1:$B10), if(ArrayFormula(LOOKUP(2,1/($K$1:$K10="Assigned"),($I$1:$I10)))))))`

This is throwing the following error:

```
Error
Wrong number of arguments to IF. Expected between 2 and 3 arguments, but got 1 arguments.
```

Lookup in column K to see if "Distributed" or "Assigned" was the latter entry in the column, and return the other data accordingly.

Comment: Please count the open (`(`) and the closing (`)`), and note that the statement you posted has only 1 argument, and `IF()` needs 3, see: https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093364?hl=en

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can fix the syntax errors in the formula like this:

```
=arrayformula(ifs( 
  lookup(2, 1 / ($K$1:$K10 = "Distributed")), $B$1:$B10, 
  lookup(2, 1 / ($K$1:$K10 = "Assigned")), $I$1:$I10, 
  true, iferror(ø) 
))
```

Whether that is *semantically* correct depends on what you expect the formula to do.

Comment: Thanks! That got rid of that error but now getting "mismatched range" error.

I want to look in column K and see if "Distributed" or "Assigned" was the latter entry in the column, and return the other data accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

My mistake. I had a range for B and I instead of a value.

```
=arrayformula(ifs( 
  lookup(2, 1 / ($K$2:$K3 = "Distributed")), $B4-1, 
  lookup(2, 1 / ($K$2:$K3 = "Assigned")), $I3, 
  true, iferror(ø)
```

Comment: It seems you're happy with the solution here. But as I look at it, even without context of the spreadsheet, I can't help but feel that it is an inefficient formula for what it does; and that you are trying to drag this formula around to other places, whereas a single formula could likely do it all more efficiently. If you'd like to post a link to the spreadsheet (or a copy of it, or a spreadsheet containing an adequate and realistic representative sample along with your expected results), you may wind up with a better overall solution.